# Searching a 2D array of strings and outputting the location

Tags: java, arrays, search, 2d

So, I have this array:

```
    String HomeDepot[][] = {
    {"Refridgerators", "Washers", "Dryers", "Dishwashers", "Vaccum Cleaners", "Fans", "Small Appliances"},
    {"Sinks", "Tubs", "Showers", "Toilets", "Facuets"},
    {"Lumber", "Doors", "Windows", "Drywall", "Fireplaces", "Ladders", "Insulation", "Decking", "Hardware"},
    {"Blinds", "Rugs", "Shelves", "Mirrors", "Wallpaper", "Furntiture"},
    {"Wire", "Heaters", "Light Bulbs", "Smoke Alarms", "Extension Chords"},
    {"Flooring" , "Tile", "Laminate", "Hardwood"},
    {"Cabinets", "Bookcases", "Door Knobs"},
    {"Chandeliers", "Lamps", "Outdoor Lighting", "Lamp Shades"},
    {"Paint", "Brushes", "Spray Paint", "Paint Samples", "Wood Stain"},
{"Power Tools", "Tool Accessories", "Tool Storage"}
    };
```

And I'd like to search it for a user-prompted query (like this):

```
    String item;
    item = JOptionPane.showInpuDialog("What would you like to search for? Please capitalize your query.");
```

And I just can't seem to get it to work! I'd like it to search the array for the user's item, and upon finding it. output the location of the item. If the item isn't in the array, I'd like it to ask if the user would like to search again, or give up.  Please help! I'm using java.

Comment: I've tried a variety of for loops and booleans, and the closest I ever got was it would compile just fine, but upon running it it just said, "Item is not found".

Comment: Can you show us what code you've tried?  Plus, I don't know what you mean by "output the location"... there don't appear to be any locations in your array (unless `HomeDepot` is the location!?).  Plus you need to add "Drop Cloths" to the list of products so that you don't get paint all over the floor when you're painting (OK, I realize that's not a Java problem... :)

Comment: @ajb By output the location I mean give the location in the array of the item (for example, if you looked up "Lamps", it would say, "Lamps was found at [7,1] or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
String item;
int[] coords = new int[2];

boolean finished = false;
while(!finished){ // if we don't find what you searched, then keep checking
   item = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What would you like to search for?");
   for(int i = 0; i < HomeDepot.length; i++) { 
       for(int j = 0; j < HomeDepot[i].length; j++) {
           if(HomeDepot[i][j].equals(item)) {
               coords[0] = i;
               coords[1] = j;
               finished = true;
           }
           if(finished) break; 
       } 
       if(finished) break;
   }
   if(!finished)
      System.out.println("Could not find " + item + "! Please try again.");
}
System.out.println(coords[0] + "," + coords[1]); // prints the location once you've
                                                 // searched a valid String in the matrix
```

This will give you a tuple with the row and column of the item, if it exists.

Comment: Your answer compiles, but upon running gives an error that says, "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7"

Comment: A tuple is just an ordered set of items. In this case, our tuple is `coords`, which contains two ordered elements: the first one is the row the item is in, and the second is the column (i.e. the index of that row) which is it in. For example, if you searched for "Dryers", your tuple would contain 0 at position 0 (coords[0] == 0), and 2 at position 1 (coords[1] == 2).

Comment: This should not give an OutOfBoundsException - the indexes can never be exceeded since they are bounded by the length of the array and its subarrays. Can you check so that you did not accidentally replace an "i" with a "j" or vice versa?

Comment: Note that Java lets you put a label on a loop and use the label in the `break` statement, so that you could actually break out of both loops instead of using two `break` statements.

Comment: OH MY GOD IT WORKS I LOVE YOU CHRSVA

Comment: Hehe glad it got sorted! Happy coding :)